# Leave Polymeric Sand Until Tomorrow?

Tags: patio, pavers

I was told I only needed 2 bags of polymeric sand for my project. It's turning out I need more. I used the two bags and my project is not complete, I haven't shaken it down yet, and I can't buy more in my location until tomorrow. Should I Just activate what's there? Would putting a tarp over it prevent the dew from messing with it overnight? Would dew not even mess with it? What should I do?? I used G2 Intelligent Polymeric Sand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer isn't quite straight-forward, but the tarp was probably the best option. When I lifted the tarp, half of the tarp had dew on the bottom o fit--the half still in the shade. So the other half may have had dew as well but dried out before I lifted it. Despite this, the bricks and sand were entirely dry apart from what drips fell when I lifted the tarp and the sand was definitely not activated. Results may then vary I guess, but it worked for me :-).

Comment: In retrospect, I shouldn't have let the tarp dry out over the lawn for a few hours. There is a very nice square brown spot in the lawn now... :-P